# Raphaël.js, event on one path triggers event on another path

Tags: javascript, raphael

I have a path that when moused over I would like an animation of another path to happen. You can see the image below. When a user hovers over a region I would like the white dot to animate.

Code sample:

```
for (key in regionsConfig) {
paper.setStart();
paper
    .path(regionsConfig[key].path)
    .attr(regionsConfig[key].attrs)
    .data('url', regionsConfig[key].url)
    .data('fill', regionsConfig[key].attrs.fill);
paper.circle(regionsConfig[key].circle.x, regionsConfig[key].circle.y, 4).attr({ fill: '#fff', 'stroke-width': 0 });
switch (key) {
    case 'nRegion':
        shapes[key] = paper.text(220, 75, 'Northern').attr({fill: '#fff', 'font-size': 40, 'font-family': 'GarageGothic Regular'});
        break;
    case 'nwRegion':
        shapes[key] = paper.text(80, 420, 'Northern Western').attr({fill: '#5e2b12', 'font-size': 40, 'font-family': 'GarageGothic Regular'});
        break;
    case 'ncRegion':
        shapes[key] = paper.text(340, 230, 'Northern Central').attr({fill: '#fff', 'font-size': 40, 'font-family': 'GarageGothic Regular'});
        break;
    case 'cRegion':
        shapes[key] = paper.text(280, 380, 'Central').attr({fill: '#fff', 'font-size': 40, 'font-family': 'GarageGothic Regular'});
        break;
    case 'sRegion':
        shapes[key] = paper.text(250, 580, 'Southern').attr({fill: '#5e2b12', 'font-size': 40, 'font-family': 'GarageGothic Regular'});
        break;
}
shapes[key] = paper.setFinish();
console.log(shapes[key]);
shapes[key].click(function() {
    console.log(this);
    this.attr({fill: 'black'});
});
shapes[key].mouseover(function() {
    this.animate({
        fill: '#337891',
        'stroke-width': 3
    }, 500);
});
shapes[key].mouseout(function() {
    this.animate({
        fill: this.data('fill'),
        'stroke-width': 1
    }, 500);
});
```

[image: map of nevada]

Comment: activate the dot animation in a hover callback? have you tried anything?

Comment: I grouped the shape, circle, and text into a single group. I have a hover event for the group but I don't know how single out the circle to trigger it's event.

Comment: enclosing some code will go a long way in helping us help you.

Comment: Edited to add a code sample

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Missed your set at first, but I think you would probably still need a closure for either the set or circle, so the hover funcs know what they are referencing after the loop, so untested code/psuedocode something like...

```
...loop

(function() {

     var dot = paper.circle(regionsConfig[key].circle.x, regionsConfig[key].circle.y, 4).attr({ fill: '#fff', 'stroke-width': 0 });

     ...

    shapes[ key ].mouseover(function() {
         dot.animate({
             fill: '#337891',
             'stroke-width': 3
         }, 500);

     });
    shapes[ key ].mouseout(function() {
        dot.animate({
            fill: this.data('fill'),
            'stroke-width': 1
        }, 500);

    });
})();

...endloop
```

If you need, you could put it on a jsfiddle and it should be feasible to get it going, if you haven't managed with the above.

edit: not quite sure I've got my closures right without a fiddle, but hopefully you get the overall idea.